# How to change the logger associated to logging.captureWarnings()?

Tags: python, logging, deprecation-warning

In my application, I'm using [`logging.captureWarnings(True)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.captureWarnings) to make sure any [`DeprecationWarning`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.DeprecationWarning) gets logged in the normal application log.

This works well, but results in logs like:

```
WARNING [py.warnings] c:\some\path...
```

It seems [from the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.captureWarnings) that:

> If capture is True, warnings issued by the warnings module will be
>   redirected to the logging system. Specifically, a warning will be
>   formatted using warnings.formatwarning() and the resulting string
>   logged to **a logger named 'py.warnings'** with a severity of WARNING.

So that is all to be expected. But I'd like to change the logger associated to such warnings (use the one my application provides, so that one can know when looking at the logs where the `DeprecationWarning` comes from).

Is there a way to change the associated logger ?

Answer (score 2):

I just did some more investigation and found a perfect way to achieve that:

Looking at the source code for `logging.captureWarnings()`:

```
def captureWarnings(capture):
    """
    If capture is true, redirect all warnings to the logging package.
    If capture is False, ensure that warnings are not redirected to logging
    but to their original destinations.
    """
    global _warnings_showwarning
    if capture:
        if _warnings_showwarning is None:
            _warnings_showwarning = warnings.showwarning
            warnings.showwarning = _showwarning
    else:
        if _warnings_showwarning is not None:
            warnings.showwarning = _warnings_showwarning
            _warnings_showwarning = None
```

It seems one can just change `warnings.showwarning` to point to another callable that will do whatever logging job you want (or anything else for that matter).

The expected prototype for `warnings.showwarning` seems to be:

```
def _show_warning(message, category, filename, lineno, file=None, line=None):
    """Hook to write a warning to a file; replace if you like."""
    if file is None:
        file = sys.stderr
    try:
        file.write(formatwarning(message, category, filename, lineno, line))
    except IOError:
        pass # the file (probably stderr) is invalid - this warning gets lost.
```

It seems `logging.captureWarnings()` actually sets the callable to `logging._showwarning`:

```
def _showwarning(message, category, filename, lineno, file=None, line=None):
    """
    Implementation of showwarnings which redirects to logging, which will first
    check to see if the file parameter is None. If a file is specified, it will
    delegate to the original warnings implementation of showwarning. Otherwise,
    it will call warnings.formatwarning and will log the resulting string to a
    warnings logger named "py.warnings" with level logging.WARNING.
    """
    if file is not None:
        if _warnings_showwarning is not None:
            _warnings_showwarning(message, category, filename, lineno, file, line)
    else:
        s = warnings.formatwarning(message, category, filename, lineno, line)
        logger = getLogger("py.warnings")
        if not logger.handlers:
            logger.addHandler(NullHandler())
        logger.warning("%s", s)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternate approach to the one detailed by @ereOn. This approach opts to use `warnings.catch_warnings()` and `logging.warning()` instead of redefining `logging._showwarnings`.

```
import warnings
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(<your logger name>)

# catch warnings
with warnings.catch_warnings(record=True) as ww:
    warnings.warn('HELLOQ') # example warning

# log warnings
for w in ww:
    logger.warning(warnings.formatwarning(w.message, w.category, w.filename, w.lineno))
```

The location/file your warnings are logged to will be determined when you configure a file handler for "".